# Table to Matrix to Dendrogram

Tags: r

Everyone.
I'm trying to make a dendogram of similarity, and my dataset is composed of 2 categorical variables and one continuous. And to make a dendogram I **think** I need to transform this structure into matrix, as the following example that I build to ilustrate that.

[image: Analogy of my case]

Comment: I forgot the question: How can I make it in R?

Comment: Use the `table` function.

Comment: Provide your data using `dput(data)` not as a picture. We cannot illustrate a solution with a picture. After you create the matrix, you will need to create a similarity/distance matrix and then create a dendrogram from that matrix.